# How can I match text and replace it with a computed value based on the match in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a function, call it `f`, that takes a string and returns a string.

I have a file with lines that look like this:

`stuff:morestuff:stuff*:otherstuff:otherstuff*\n`

Colons only appear as delimiters and * only appears at the end of each word.  I want to loop over the file and replace all instances of stuff* with f(stuff).  The previous line would go to

`stuff:morestuff:f(stuff):otherstuff:f(otherstuff)\n`

I can do this in a few lines, but there must be a way to do it in one.

**Edit**
To be clear, by f(stuff), I mean f called on "stuff", not the string "f(stuff)".

Comment: Hah, "I can do this in a few lines, but there must be a way to do it in one.", this is why I can't stand Perl.

Comment: @Pace - this is why you can't stand *some* of Perl programmers. Perl has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You can't stand Perl because it takes common operations and gives you the power to do them with little typing? The point of higher level languages it to give you higher level concepts so you don't have to juggle many statements yourself. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you [use the `e` option for `s//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) then the right hand expression is evaluated as code.  So this is as simple as:

```
$line =~ s/([^:]+)\*/f($1)/ge;
```

Breaking down the match:

- `(` starts marking part of the pattern
- `[^:]` means anything but a `:`
- `+` means one or more of these, i.e. one or more characters that's not a colon
- `)` ends marking part of the pattern as `$1`
- `\*` means literally a `*`

This pattern is relying on the fact that `*` only appears at the end of each word.  If it could appear in the middle of a field you'd need to tweak the pattern a little.

Or, putting the pattern in a whole script:

```
sub f {
    my $word = shift;
    $word =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
    return $word;
}

while (<>) {
    s/([^:]+)\*/f($1)/ge;
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it this way:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

sub f { uc reverse $_[0] }

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  my $out = join ":" =>
            map s/(stuff)\*$/$1/ ? f($_) : $_,
            split /:/;

  print $out, "\n";
}

__DATA__
stuff:morestuff:stuff*:otherstuff:otherstuff*
otherstuff
stuff
stuff*
stuff*:otherstuff*
```

Output:

```
stuff:morestuff:FFUTS:otherstuff:FFUTSREHTO
otherstuff
stuff
FFUTS
FFUTS:FFUTSREHTO
```

But if you have allinoneregexitis, go with

```
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  s/  (?:^|(?<=:))     # BOL or just after colon
      ([^:]*stuff)\*   # ending with 'stuff*'
      (?=:|$)          # at EOL or just before colon
  / f $1 /gex;

  print $_, "\n";
}
```

This works because of the [`/e` switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpogce):

> A `/e` will cause the replacement portion to be treated as a full-fledged Perl expression and evaluated right then and there.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $string =~ s{ (^|:) ([^:*]+) \* }{$1 . f($2)}gxe;
```

Should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=~s/(^|:)([^*:]*)\*(?=(:|$))/\1f\(\2\)/g;
```

-EDIT-

If f() is a function I don't see any particular reason for doing it in one line.
split - process - join

```
def f(x):
    return x.upper()

a='stuff*:morestuff:stuff*:otherstuff:otherstuff*\n';

print ':'.join([f(x[:-1]) if x[-1]=='*' else x for x in a.strip().split(':')])
```

Sounds just as simple as the task. I love python ;)

Comment: The question is tagged as Perl so I'm not sure an answer in Python is all that helpful.